# Checking days which are closest

Tags: date, comparison

This is going to be a bit hard to explain but

I have 2 dates, i'm interested in the day and month unless the 2 dates have the same year

2015/12/30 and 2019/01/04

ignoring the year part (kind of) the **result i'm expecting 6 days difference** for the 2 dates above

if i was to use date.DayOfYear i would get 364 (2015/12/30) and 4 (2019/01/04) respectively

however if the years are same then 
 2019/01/04  2019/12/30  then the result i'm expecting **is 359 days difference**

is there a clever way of doing this without peppering the code with if statements?

Answer (score 0):

If the year difference was just 0 or 1, then you could just convert both dates to an absolute value (in seconds, ms, unix time or whatever), subtract the 2 values and convert it to full days. But if you have more than 1 year diff (as 2015 and 2019), then you have to have an "if" an think about what are you actually trying to do there. You shouldn't use DayOfYear, because some years have 366 days, so you can't be sure that 364 corresponds to 1 or 2 days left in that year.